# Getting strange error when loading component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Getting so frustrated on trying to load my second component in my app.js. I alos have one called . I keep getting this error, and I don't understand why. :

> Failed to load
>   bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false)
>   with error:(SyntaxError:
>   /Users/vemundeldegard/AwesomeProject/app/screens/Home.js: Adjacent JSX
>   elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX
>   fragment <>...? (199:6)

Loading this in my app.js

```
import Comments from '../components/Comments'

<Comments
  addComment=""
/>
```

The component file is like this:

```
const Comments = (props) => {
  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      paddingLeft: 15,
      paddingRight: 15,
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      justifyContent: 'space-between',
    },
    button: {
      padding: 10,
      height: 30,
      backgroundColor: "#eee"
    },
    buttonText: {
      fontSize:11
    },
    field: {
      fontSize:13,
      position: "relative",
      left: -3,
      top: -10,
    }
});
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <Input style={styles.field}
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      placeholder="Skriv en kommentar..."
    />
    <Button rounded style={styles.button} onPress={() => props.addComment()}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Kommenter</Text>
    </Button>
    </View>
  )
}
export Comments;

Whole app.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import {
  Alert,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  FlatList,
  ScrollView,
  Modal,
  TouchableHighlight,
  RefreshControl,
  Image
} from 'react-native';
import { Icon, Textarea, Container, Form, Content, Button, Input, Item, Label } from 'native-base';
import { firestore, settings } from '../Fire';
import moment from 'moment';
import Swiper from 'react-native-swiper';
import { RenderImage } from '../components/RenderImage'
import { Post } from '../components/Post'
import Comments from '../components/Comments'
export default class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      getData: [],
      liked: false,
      displayName:''
    }
    this.ref = firestore.collection("tips").orderBy("date", "desc");
  }


  state = { currentUser: null }


  signOutUser = () => {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      console.log("user signed out")
    }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error.toString())
    });
  }
  deleteAccount = () => {
    firebase.auth().currentUser.delete().then(function () {
      console.log('delete successful?')
      console.log(app.auth().currentUser)
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.error({error})
    })
  }
  updateUser = (displayName) => {
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let date = new moment().format("YYYYMMDD HHmmss");
      user.updateProfile({
        displayName: displayName,
        lastUpdated: date
      }).then(function() {
        alert("Updated!")
      }).catch(function(error) {
        alert("Error!")
      });
  }
  newTips = () => {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified, currentUser, displayName;
    let date = new moment().format("YYYYMMDD HHmmss");
    let tips=this.state.tips;

    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

      if (user) {
        email = user.displayName;
        // User is signed in.
        console.log('Logged in user: ' + email)
        firestore.collection("tips").add({
            user: user.displayName,
            date: date,
            tips: tips,
            like: 0,
        })
        .then(function(docRef) {
            console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
      } else {
        // User is signed out.
        console.log('No user signed in')
      }
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getItems();
    const { currentUser } = firebase.auth();
    this.setState({ currentUser });
  }

  getItems = async () => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: true });
    this.unsubscribe = await this.ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
          const todos = [];
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            todos.push({
              id: doc.id,
              tips: doc.data().tips,
              date: doc.data().date,
              user: doc.data().user,
              like: doc.data().like,
            })
            this.ref.get().then(function(documentSnapshot) {
              // check and do something with the data here.
            });
          })
          this.setState({
            refreshing: false,
            getData: todos
          })
        })
  }



  likePost = (author, id) => {

    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    let name, email, photoUrl, uid, emailVerified, currentUser, displayName;
    let date = new moment().format("YYYYMMDD HHmmss");

    firestore.collection("tips").doc(id).update({
      likes: {
          user: user.uid
      }
    })
    .then(function() {
        alert("Liked the post " + id)
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        alert("Error writing document: ", user.uid, error);
    });
    this.liked()
  }
  liked(){
    this.setState({
      liked: !this.state.liked
    })
  }
  deletePost = (author, id) => {
    let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    const { currentUser } = this.state;
    const currentUsername = currentUser && currentUser.displayName;
    if (currentUsername == author) {
      Alert.alert(
  'Er du sikker?',
  'Du sletter nå denne posten...',
  [
    {text: 'Nei', onPress: () => {

    }, style: 'cancel'},
    {text: 'Ja', onPress: () => {
      firestore.collection("tips").doc(id).delete().then(function() {
           alert("Posten er slettet!")
       }).catch(function(error) {
           alert("Error removing document: ", error);
       });
    }},
  ]
);

     }
     else {
       alert("Not your post " + currentUsername  + " its " + author)
     }
  }
  viewComments = () => {
    alert("View Comments!!")
  }
  renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    return (
      <View>
      <Post
        author={item.user}
        date={ moment(item.date).fromNow() }
        entry={item.tips}
        likes={item.like}
        id={item.id}
        image="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/c5/89/19/c589198a4e4a4b2b54ebb3852ea4bd8b.jpg"
        commentCount="123"
        like={this.likePost}
        delete={this.deletePost}
        goComments={this.viewComments}
        liked={this.state.liked}
      />

      <Comments
        addComment=""
      />
      </View>
    )
  }
  _renderEmpty= () => {
    return (
      <Text>There is no tips...</Text>
    )
  }
  _renderFooter = () => {
    return (
      <Text>All tips has been loaded...</Text>
    )
  }
  _keyExtractor = (item, index) => item.id;
  _onRefresh = () => this.getItems();

  state = {
    modalVisible: false,
    refreshing: true, // whether comments list is being refreshed or not
  };
  render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.state
    return (
      <Swiper
        loop={false}
        showsPagination={false}
        index={1}
        ref='swiper'
      >
      <View style={share.container}>
      <Form>
      <Textarea
      ref= {(el) => { this.tips = el; }}
      onChangeText={(tips) => this.setState({tips})}
      value={this.state.tips}
        placeholderTextColor={'#FFF'}
        style={{ fontSize: 38, color: '#FFF'}}
        rowSpan={10}
        placeholder="Share your best vegan tips with people near you.."
        adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}
      />
      <Button
      rounded
      style={form.button}
      onPress={() => {
        this.newTips()
        this.refs.swiper.scrollBy(1)
      }
      }
    >
    <Text style={{color: '#FFF'}}>Share</Text>
    </Button>

  </Form>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.container}>
      <FlatList style={styles.flatlist}
        data={this.state.getData}
        renderItem={this.renderItem}
        ListEmptyComponent={this._renderEmpty}
        ListFooterComponent={this._renderFooter}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        refreshControl={
          <RefreshControl
            refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
            onRefresh={this._onRefresh}
          />
        }
      >
      </FlatList>
      </View>
      <View>
        <Text>3</Text>
      </View>
      </Swiper>
    );
  }
}
const profile = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#EEF2E8',
    flex:1,
    paddingTop: 40,
    padding: 10,
  }
})
const title = StyleSheet.create({
  h1: {
    fontSize:32,
    color: "#70B21B",
    paddingLeft: 8,
    marginBottom: 10,
  }
})
const form = StyleSheet.create({
  input: {
    marginRight: 15,
  },
  button: {
    backgroundColor: '#ADDF6F',
    color: '#FFF',
    fontWeight: '600',
    paddingLeft: 20,
    paddingRight: 20,
    marginTop: 15,
    marginLeft: 10,
    marginRight: 10,
  }
})
const share = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#D0E8B2',
    flex:1,
    paddingTop: 40,
    padding: 10,
  }
})
const modal = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex:1,
    padding: 10,
    backgroundColor:'rgba(255,255,255,0.8)',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    textAlign: 'center',
  }
})
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor: '#FFF'
  },
  flatlist: {

  },
})
```

Comment: Is there a `Home.js`? If so, can we see it? How does your whole App look like?

Comment: Not strange, and if you search the web for the error message, you will get many, many hits, including on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions in javascript can only return one data structure per call. Think of each element in the JSX syntax as a function, because that is what they are. You need to return one element (function), or an array of elements (an array of functions). Before React 16, the way around this error was to wrap each group of elements in a div. Either that or you could return an array of elements (but you have to supply a key). If you are using React16, you can use a `Fragment`. They look like this.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react;

class Hello extends React.Component {

   render() {
       return (
           <Fragment>
               <h1>Hello</h1>
               <h2>World</h2>
           </Fragment>
       );
    }
}
```

This way you don't add extra markup to the DOM that is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply. Solved my issue perfectly. Where not aware of this, thanks Matt. :)

Answer (score 0):

React wants you to have JSX structured in a certain way. Wrap what you have inside a `<div>` tag.

Comment: So you are suggesting wrapping my <Post /> and <Comments /> in a View for example?

Comment: <div> <View style={styles.container}>
    <Input style={styles.field}
      autoCorrect={false}
      autoCapitalize="none"
      placeholder="Skriv en kommentar..."
    />
    <Button rounded style={styles.button} onPress={() => props.addComment()}>
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Kommenter</Text>
    </Button>
    </View>
</div>

Comment: I am using React Native, so can't use div. But I got a new error when wrapping it in <View>. ´Failed to load bundle(http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minify=false) with error:(SyntaxError: /Users/vemundeldegard/AwesomeProject/app/components/Comments.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'exportDefaultFrom' isn't currently enabled (57:8):´

Comment: Try wrapping it with ` <React.Fragment>` instead. https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html

Answer (score 0):

The error basically states that React wants the JSX elements to be contained with a single JSX element: div, span, ...etc.

However, there are several ways of accomplishing the desired result:

Old way (React 15 and below -- using a span):

```
<span>
  <Input 
    style={styles.field} 
    autoCorrect={false} 
    autoCapitalize="none" 
    placeholder="Skriv en kommentar..." 
  /> 
  <Button 
    rounded 
    style={styles.button} 
    onPress={() => props.addComment()}
  >
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Kommenter</Text> 
  </Button>
</span>
```

React 16+ (`<Fragment> ... </Fragment>`):

```
<Fragment>
  <Input 
    style={styles.field} 
    autoCorrect={false} 
    autoCapitalize="none" 
    placeholder="Skriv en kommentar..." 
  /> 
  <Button 
    rounded 
    style={styles.button} 
    onPress={() => props.addComment()}
  >
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Kommenter</Text> 
  </Button>
</Fragment>
```

React 16+ (`[ array with keys ]`):

```
[ 
  <Input
    key="comment-input" 
    style={styles.field} 
    autoCorrect={false} 
    autoCapitalize="none" 
    placeholder="Skriv en kommentar..." 
  />, 
  <Button 
    rounded
    key="add-comment-button" 
    style={styles.button} 
    onPress={() => props.addComment()}
  >
    <Text style={styles.buttonText}>Kommenter</Text> 
  </Button>
]
```